# How to get the images or frames from a video stream?

Tags: c#, arm, win-universal-app

I'm trying to find a way to get video frames from a stream so that the frames can be sent over a network in real-time. The video stream comes from a USB webcam and records to an [in-memory random-access stream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br241720) (strm).

```
deviceSettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
deviceSettings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Video;
mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(deviceSettings);

MediaEncodingProfile recordProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);
IRandomAccessStream strm = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await mediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(recordProfile, strm);

strmSize = (uint)strm.Size;
using (var datareader = new DataReader(strm.GetInputStreamAt(strmSize)))
{
    //Here I want to get the byte length that would represent the image to be read
    //but we don't know how many bytes the image is comprised of.
    strmSize = (uint)strm.Size;

    await datareader.LoadAsync(strmSize);
    byte[] frameByte = new byte[strmSize];
    datareader.ReadBytes(frameByte);
}
```

I tried using *AForge* and *Directshow* in Windows 10 apps using *AForge.Video.dll* and *AForge.Video.DirectShow.dll* but the libraries are not supported according to me testing it and [wikipedia reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Foundation).

Comment: Without knowing the stream's format is going to be very difficult to anyone help you

Comment: Please see my edit. Hope I understand what you mean by "format".

Comment: I mean the stream format, for what I see it's an mp4 stream?

Comment: Yes, it is mp4. Although it should preferably record video only. See edit.

Comment: If its encoded as mp4 it's likely using h264 codec, in this case you wont get individual frames from it in the way you desire. If it was MJPEG you could pull images out. Here's a tip, write the data to a file and then open the file with MediaInfo, it can detect if the data is part of a h264 stream and let you know. Heres a video of me reverse engineering a security camera protocol and getting it to play in FFPlay. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NTTIqQMTniI I think it should give you some tips to reverse engineer your stream.

Comment: @WHol I don't think that can be doable on an universal app (@Jnr, that's an universal app, yes?) Also, if that's h.264 then it's perfect for streaming, doing any conversion will be just a waste of resources, for sure your frame-by-frame solution will be a lot worse than h.264.

Comment: @Gusman I am using the uwp. As for what compression to use, if its possible with h264 then I would rather go that way because there is no out-of-the-box compression for MJPEG in uwp - I will have to write my own.

Comment: But if the stream is already mp4/h264 why don't you just retransmit it as-is?

Comment: @Gusman Can you elaborate what you mean? Do you mean stream the video without using individual frames?

Comment: Yes, just stream the bytes you received as-is and forget about processing it on the app, it's already a format specifically created for streaming so you should have no problem.

Comment: If you're writing to the network using a StreamSocket, then it's even easier, pass the OutputStream of the socket to the StartRecordToStreamAsync and you're done, you don't even need to receive the data it can be streamed directly

Comment: It's interesting what you are stating here @Gusman . I am currently using the DatagramSocket for UDP because it uses less bandwidth, no congestion control, and a small percentage of data loss would be ok. I need to stream the data in real-time. TCP uses the StreamSocket and because TCP uses congestion that could cause the video to not stream in real-time.

Comment: Hmm, with UDP you will have a ton of problems unless you're on a local network (and if you're on local network then congestion will not be a problem), you will face very easily situations where the packets cannot be delivered because the sender/receiver is behind a network where UDP is not routed, so I don't think that's a good idea, that's just my experience.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104857/discussion-between-jnr-and-gusman).